# Sorting a text file based on numerical values present in each line

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sort

I have a text file containing paths of various wav files. But when they are created they are sorted based on alphabetical order. Hence the paths are like this

```
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_100.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_101.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_102.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_103.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_104.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_105.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_106.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_107.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_108.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_109.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_10.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_110.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_111.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_11.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_12.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_13.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_14.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_15.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_16.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_17.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_18.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_19.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_1.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_20.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_21.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_22.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_23.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_24.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_25.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_26.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_27.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_28.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_29.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_2.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_30.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_31.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_32.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_33.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_34.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_35.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_36.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_37.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_38.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_39.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_3.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_40.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_41.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_42.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_43.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_44.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_45.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_46.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_47.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_48.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_49.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_4.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_50.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_51.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_52.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_53.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_54.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_55.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_56.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_57.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_58.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_59.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_5.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_60.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_61.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_62.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_63.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_64.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_65.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_66.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_67.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_68.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_69.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_6.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_70.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_71.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_72.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_73.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_74.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_75.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_76.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_77.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_78.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_79.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_7.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_80.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_81.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_82.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_83.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_84.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_85.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_86.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_87.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_88.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_89.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_8.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_90.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_91.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_92.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_93.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_94.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_95.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_98.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_99.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_9.wav
```

I want them to be sorted based on the numerics after TC, so that they can be like this

```
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_1.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_2.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_3.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_4.wav
```

I have tried using `sort` and `sort -n` but none are working. Can anyone please help me with how to do this?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/760445/70524

Comment: closed on U&L, so not closing here. @graham this question is perfectly on topic here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to specify the underscore character `_` as a field separator with `-t '_'` and then sort on the fifth field with `-k 5` numerically with `-n` like this:

```
sort -n -t '_' -k 5,5 file
```